# Is there a limit on how anaphoric a language can be before it becomes incomprehensible?

Tags: anaphora

Consider dependency grammars where each lexical element appears to in some way refer back to or be governed by another word in the sentence.

I think it would be like, “the blue jacket” = the -> jacket -> blue ?

Or, jacket (<- blue, the) (they both depend on jacket?)

For stuff like coordination, it also seems there is multiple elements pointing at the same head, like “and” <- (French fries, Coca Cola).

I have been thinking about a claim that a language does not need “recursion”, and I am wondering if the only real way to spell out what that means is actually, that a language does not need deterministically parsible dependency-relations.

Here is why I think that.

An example to confirm the idea that you can reformulate any sentence in English with coordination is easy:

I like cheese and ham. ->

I like cheese. And I like ham.

It is as if we have the right to break what was previously a strongly determined syntactic relationship, because it is easy to anaphorically assume the relationship, once they are separated into sentences.

One of the advantages splitting a syntactic form, so the relation is now implicit, not explicit, for coordination, is that coordination often coordinates two complete sentences or clauses. So the result doesn’t seem awkward, because you sort of split SP CONJ SP into SP. CONJ SP.

But this doesn’t work syntactically when you split two elements that are not both capable of existing on their own as individual sentences:

I think that Ali is lying. ->

I think. / I think that.

Ali is lying.

You are forced to insert null elements which can be resolved anaphorically, like this:

I think something.

It is, “Ali is lying.” / It is that Ali is lying. / That something is that Ali is lying.

Or

I have a green, green backpack which I like to put food in.

There are levels to which you can try to split all of the dependencies.

Like:

1. I have a green, green backpack.
2. I like to put food in it.

Vs:

1. I have something.
2. It is a backpack.
3. It is green-green (?).
4. I like something.
5. That something, is putting.
6. That putting, is putting food.
7. And that thing (that I like doing), is specifically, inside the other thing (that I mentioned before).

It seems that the more you separate specific dependencies that English grammar allows you to immediately get, you have to use more complex anaphoric constructions to supply enough contextual information to help someone figure out what of the many past referents (= any of the words) you are adding another linked word to.

It might reach the point where you redundantly rephrase what you already said:

I like something. And that something that I like, is water skiing.

One way to avoid this is to give every referent a unique identifier.

John<sub>i</sub>

likes<sub>j</sub>

i j (like, j links to i).

This is how programming languages work. Every single element can be given an identifier, so you can point to anything immediately, and use it syntactically, by grabbing its “handle” (its name, its id).

So.

If someone says language does not need recursion because coordinated clauses can be split into adjacent sentences and the same meaning can be understood anaphorically, I do not think they are talking about recursion, they are talking about dependency in general. In this context, recursion is not interesting, if by recursion you specifically mean a way to link syntactic elements and produce the same syntactic type. Recursion just means infinitude, in that case. But even without recursion, for a finite language with tons of linking rules, you can make the same claim that “linking isn’t required, you can always split links and it’s still understandable.”

It appears to be that even if in surface structure there are ways to not have to deterministically mark all dependencies, it is not interesting, because when a sentence is understood in some “Language of Thought”, it will be necessary for the person to have all those relationships understood, to understand what somebody is saying:

“There is a monkey in the tree outside my window.” =>

Monkey (a)
Tree (b)
Window (c)
Outside (d)
My (e)
In (f)
the (g)
is (h)

etc.

a h
b h
c h
a d
d c
c e

Which says:

1. There is a monkey, a tree, and a window.
2. The monkey is outside (something).
3. The “outside”, is to the window.
4. The window, is “my”.

And so on.

It comes to seem trivial to judge language by its syntactic structure if we consider that the language of thought should probably be the same, regardless (roughly, its implied structure, anyway).

I think it means that meaning is inherently relational. It is not meaningful to distinguish between languages with and without recursion or embedding or subordination. Regardless of how they express those relations in their actual grammar, it would be impossible to model such thoughts, without being capable of thinking of nested or linked relationships between things - including recursive ones (like, I like my friend who likes me.)

I think that still leaves open a question, maybe cross-linguistically, how much anaphora or implicitness we see in languages, before comprehension begins to fall apart and one is unable to infer relationships whatsoever. For example, a language of single-word sentences.